# React Admin routing

Tags: node.js, reactjs, ejs

I am trying to make my first website that has only one admin, once this admin signs in the website will display the Admin button, and when the admin clicks on it it will go to this path shopMembers/adminProfile. The problem here is all the websites' members can go to the adminProfile if they singed in and typed shopMembers/adminProfile at the search box of the browser.

shopUsers-routes.js

```
.
.
router.get('/adminProfile',  isAuthenticated, (req, res)=>{
    res.render('shopMembers/adminProfile', {
            success: req.flash('success')
    })
})
.
.
```

navbar.ejs

```
.
.
<% if ((user) && (user.email == "abodn70@hotmail.com")) {%>
                       
  <li><a href="/shopUsers/adminProfile" id="admin" style="color:red">Admin</a></li>
  <% }%>
.
.
```

pass-Suser.js

```
const passport = require('passport')
const localStrategy = require('passport-local').Strategy
const SUser = require('../models/shopUser')


//saving user object in the session 
passport.serializeUser(function(user, done) {
    done(null, user.id);
  });
  
  passport.deserializeUser(function(id, done) {
    SUser.findById(id, function(err, user) {
      done(err, user);
    });
  });

// user signup
passport.use('local.signup', new localStrategy({
    usernameField : 'email',
    passwordField: 'password',

    passReqToCallback: true
}, (req,username,password, done)=> {
    if (req.body.password != req.body.confirm_passwordUS) {
        return done(null, false, req.flash('error', 'Passwords not match'))
    } else {
        SUser.findOne({email: username}, (err,user)=>{
            if (err){
                return done(err)
            }
            if (user){
                return done(null, false, req.flash('error', 'Email already used'))
            }
            if (!user){
                //Creat user
                
                let newUser = new SUser()
                newUser.email= req.body.email,
                newUser.password= newUser.hashPassword(req.body.password),
                newUser.firstName= req.body.Fname,
                newUser.lastName= req.body.Lname,
                newUser.userName= req.body.UserName

              //  newUser.avatar= "user.png"
                newUser.save((err, user)=>{
                    if(!err){
                        console.log(newUser)
                        return done(null, user, req.flash('success', 'User Added'))
 
                    }
                    else{
                        console.log(err)
                    }

                })
            }
        }  )
    }

}))

//user login

passport.use('local.login', new localStrategy({
    usernameField : 'email',
    passwordField: 'password',
    passReqToCallback: true

},(req, username, password, done)=>{
    // find user
    SUser.findOne({email: username}, (err,user)=> {

        if (err) {
            return done(null, false, req.flash('error', 'Something wrong happened'))
        } 
        if(!user) {
            return done(null, false, req.flash('error', 'user was not found'))
        }
   //     if(!user.confirmed){
   //         return done(null, false, req.flash('error', 'user has not confirmed the account'))
  //      }
        if (user) {
            if (user.comparePasswords(password, user.password)) {

                return done(null,user, req.flash('success', ' welcome back'))

            } else {
                return done(null,false, req.flash('error', ' password is wrong'))

            }
        }
    })
}))
```

app.js

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express()
const db = require ('./config/database.js') //connect to database
var bodyParser = require('body-parser')
const session= require('express-session')
const flash= require('connect-flash')
const passport = require("passport");
const pSU = require('./config/pass-Suser') 
const router = express.Router();

.
.
.
//session and flash config
app.use(session({
  secret: 'keyboard cat',
  resave: false,
  saveUninitialized: true,
  cookie: { maxAge: 60000 *15  }
}))
app.use(flash())

//bring passport 
app.use(passport.initialize())
app.use(passport.session())

// store user object
app.get('*', (req,res,next)=> {
  res.locals.user = req.user || null
  next()
})
.
.
```

Comment: so how do you authenticate users?

Comment: I am using passportjs, I have added the class to my question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hiding the link on the front end is, like you noticed, pointless. You need to implement the permission logic on the server. I haven't used Passport in a while (Meteor nowadays takes care of that nicely), but something like this should work:

```
app.get('/shopUsers/adminProfile', (req, res, next)=> {
  if (req.user.email != 'abodn70@hotmail.com') {
    // disallowed
    res.sendError(401);
  } else {
    next();
  }
});
```

Comment: Thank you, this is what I was looking for